# Flutter Awesome Notification Schedule

Tags: flutter

how do i create schedule notification in flutter with awesome notification? I've tried but they are calling in seconds not hours how can i change that? How can i get notification to be showed daily at same hour?

```
 Future<void> showScheduletification(
      int id, String channelKey, String title, String body, int minutes) async {
    String localTimeZone =
        await AwesomeNotifications().getLocalTimeZoneIdentifier();
    AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
        content: NotificationContent(
          id: id,
          channelKey: channelKey,
          title: title,
          body: body,
        ),
        schedule: NotificationInterval(
          interval: minutes,
          timeZone: localTimeZone,
          repeats: true,
        ));
  }
```

I've tried with some code from Youtube

Answer (score 1):

> repeats: Determines if the schedule should be repeat after be displayed. If there is no more valid date compatible with the schedule rules, the notification is automatically canceled.

NotificationCalendar has hour,minutes,sec,weekday etc as part of constructors. In this case

```dart
    await AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
      content: NotificationContent(
        id: id,
        channelKey: 'scheduled',
        title: 'Just in time!',
        body: 'This notification was schedule to shows at ' +
            (Utils.DateUtils.parseDateToString(scheduleTime.toLocal()) ?? '?') +
            ' $timeZoneIdentifier (' +
            (Utils.DateUtils.parseDateToString(scheduleTime.toUtc()) ?? '?') +
            ' utc)',
        wakeUpScreen: true,
        category: NotificationCategory.Reminder,
        notificationLayout: NotificationLayout.BigPicture,
        bigPicture: 'asset://assets/images/delivery.jpeg',
        payload: {'uuid': 'uuid-test'},
        autoDismissible: false,
      ),
      schedule: NotificationCalendar(hour: 5,repeats:true));
```